# Ember filterBy - using more than one value to filter

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

How can I use more than one value to filter a list using the filterBy function?

My scenario is - I have a list of consoles which I want to filter based on the console_id.

Unfortunately, I don't have control over the JSON so each consoles has a different ID. I would like to loop through the Console IDs within the nested assignedConsole JSON and then filter through the root assignedConsole JSON.

I can get the console ID of the first object and place it into the filter but I don't know how I can use two values

I have created a emberjs bin to demonstrate my problem: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kojute/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some clarification from my previous answer, I realized you want to filter by console instead of filtering the assignedConsole values.  My suggestion is to add a `selectedConsole` property on the controller, and display the array of `assignedConsoles` for the selected console.

Working JSBin: http://jsbin.com/nuroyuvuta/9

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** See my other answer for the working solution!

I would suggest creating a computed property on your model or your controller that flattens that nested structure for you:

```
allConsoles: function() {
  return this.get('consoles')
    .mapProperty('assignedConsoles').reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a.concat(b);
    })
    .uniq();
}.property('consoles.@each')
```

This will first get all of the items from the `consoles` property, then map all of their `assignedConsoles` to an intermediate value, which is then reduced by adding all the `assignedConsoles` together.  The final `uniq()` call just removes any duplicates found in the array.

Comment: If you could edit the jsbin with your answer, that would be a great help.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about your data source, but isn't `consoles.assignedConsoles` just an aggregation of `consoles.@each.assignedConsoles`?  If so, I'm not sure you need to filter through the root `assignedConsoles` array.

Comment: Is http://jsbin.com/nuroyuvuta/9 what you're looking for?  If so, I can update the answer.

Comment: Worked like a dream. It seems as though my way of thinking through this idea wasn't right. Thanks for you help!!!! If you add it as an answer, I will select it.